# How LazyHorizontalGrid height calculates when there are vertical space between items?

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose

As part of [Basic layouts in Compose](https://developer.android.com/codelabs/jetpack-compose-layouts?continue=https%3A%2F%2Fdeveloper.android.com%2Fcourses%2Fpathways%2Fjetpack-compose-for-android-developers-1%23codelab-https%3A%2F%2Fdeveloper.android.com%2Fcodelabs%2Fjetpack-compose-layouts#7) codelab we are going to specify the code below to satisfy these design conditions:

- The grid has horizontal contentPadding of 16.dp.
- The horizontal and vertical arrangement is spaced by 16.dp.
- The height of the grid is 168.dp.
- The modifier of the FavoriteCollectionCard specifies a height of
  80.dp.

and the code to achieve them is as follows:

```
@Composable
fun FavoriteCollectionsGrid(
    modifier: Modifier = Modifier,
) {
    LazyHorizontalGrid(
        rows = GridCells.Fixed(2),
        verticalArrangement = Arrangement.spacedBy(16.dp),
        horizontalArrangement = Arrangement.spacedBy(16.dp),
        contentPadding = PaddingValues(horizontal = 16.dp),
        modifier = modifier.height(168.dp),
    ) {
        items(favoriteCollectionsData) { (drawable, text) ->
            FavoriteCollectionCard(
                drawable = drawable,
                text = text,
                modifier = Modifier.height(80.dp)
            )
        }
    }
}
```

My question is what are the height of the grid and the vertical space between items?

Since the sum of the card's height and vertical space is greater than the height of the grid:

2 cell * card height + vertical space = 2 * 80 + 16 = 176 > 168 specified grid height

Then either the grid height is 176 or the vertical space is 8.

Answer (score 0):

After investigating the situation with Layout Inspector I realized the height of the LazyHorizontalGrid is 168 but the height of each card item is 76 to achieve the 16 dp vertical space between cards.

Each cell's height = (grid height - vertical space) / number of cells

76 = (168 - 16) / 2

In summary, LazyHorizontalGrid holds the client's specified attributes and places items in the remaining space.

[image]